# Tableless images in TYPO3 4.7?

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.7

I am stuck updating a site on TYPO3 4.7. Upgrading is not an option.

All the content elements that use images are formatted with tables and spacer.gifs, is there any way to make it use divs and css instead?

Comment: To you have installed the extension "css_styled_content"?

Comment: @MarioNaether Yes, I've included it in the template but it doesn't appear to change anything. Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

If css_styled_content is correctly installed, and you'Ve included the static template in your main template, this is indeed not the expected behaviour.

Did you flush all output caches? If so, check the value of the typoscript setting at `tt_content.image.20.renderMethod` and `tt_content.textpic.20.renderMethod`. They may be set to "table", and should be one of "figure", "ul" or "div".

However, TYPO3 4.7 is out of it's LTS phase. You need to update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

4.7 is outdated and there is no such option there, sorry